# To be DRY, can I access a string column width limit in ActiveRecord?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

In writing a Rails app there are several places where string table column widths are needed: validations, RSpec testing, input forms, etc. It seems worthwhile to set the length limit on strings in the DB also.

At present I've set a LENGTHS hash in the model so I can access the lengths in other places and keep the code DRY in this respect. If I set the length limits in the DB, is it possible to read the values from there (or initialize the LENGTHS hash with them) to make the code even more DRY? That is, what is the code to read a string length limit of a database column in the model so I can use it?

Comment: It's a very bad idea to keep this kind of configuration (that's static) in the database because your application would need to access database even it's just loading itself and not really doing any work.

Comment: From what I've read the schema data are loaded at start-up, so there is no extra DB access. I think there is far more to be gained in the usual benefits of DRYness. See: http://devblog.avdi.org/2011/10/20/drying-up-your-validations-using-db-reflection/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the columns method of your AR model.

```
Model.columns.map(&:limit)
Model.columns.map(&:name)
Model.columns.map(&:null)
Model.columns.map(&:sql_type)
...
```

So you can use this method to construct your hash/array/whatever.
I believe the **length** attibute you are talking about is **limit** in this notation.

Answer (score 0):

```
class ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.method_missing(method_id, *args)
    if self.columns_hash.has_key?(method_id.to_s)
      self.columns_hash[method_id.to_s]
    else
      super
    end
  end
end
```

This allows access to any of the column schema data supplied by `columns_hash` in a clean way. Thus:

`Model.column_name` returns the hash of all the available data

`Model.column_name.hash_key` returns one value of interest

For example:
`Company.contact_name.limit` returns the maximum length of the `contact_name` column.
From what I've read, the DB loads the schema data at startup so no DB hit occurs and `columns_hash` memoizes the data.